# How do you permanently delete a payment method from Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to delete a payment method from Stripe? I can't seem to find that functionality described anywhere in the docs. You can create a payment method, attach it to a customer, and detach it from that customer, but how do you delete the payment method from Stripe's system entirely?

If you can't, then that means once you send your credit card info to Stripe, you can't ever take it back...

Comment: You should write into support about that: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Answer (score 21):

I think the good way to do so is to **detach** the `paymentMethod` from a customer:

```js
const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.detach(
  'pm_xxx'
);
```

[Api reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/detach)

Like [@Rasmus Christoffer Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435157/how-do-you-permanently-delete-a-payment-method-from-stripe/64223149#comment115076120_64223149) said in comments, "**the payment method cannot be attached to any customer again** thus serving the purpose of deletion"

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Furthermore, once detached it cannot be attached to any customer again thus serving the purpose of deletion. When attempting to re-attach Stripe will throw the following error

"This PaymentMethod was previously used without being attached to a Customer or was detached from a Customer, and may not be used again.'"

Comment: This means, that the data remains in stripe and cannot be removed anymore? strange...

Comment: does this work only with `pm_xxx` or is it also valid for card objects with id `card_xxx`

Comment: I checked, and this method works both `pm_xxx` and `card_xxx`. This by the was should be the favoured method to delete payments since the Payments API is the what stripe is transitioning to https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning

Comment: Due to GDPR it's important that the customer can delete all their personal information. Any update if it's possible to delete permanently and not just detach?

Comment: @GossipDolphin AFAIK there is no other way to delete a payment method. Here is a related article: https://www.reddit.com/r/stripe/comments/lkak8q/is_paymentmethod_detaching_gdpr_compliant/ tell me if you find complementary informations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

1. List all cards to **find out the card's ID** you want to delete (e.g. card_1OBgbpKn8YCeyAhDlPBszNsO) if you don't have it yet:

   *const cards = await stripe.customers.listSources( customerId, { object: 'card' } )*
2. **Delete card**

   *const deletedCard = await stripe.customers.deleteSource( customerId, cardId )*
3. **Double check**

   *const success = deletedCard.deleted === true*

Answer (score 0):

you can scan the list:

1. get the customer lists by type cards:

```
cards = stripe.Customer.list_payment_methods(customer_id, type="card")
```

2. then loop and find the same fingerprint used on the client card to be removed. Remember fingerprint can be retrieved on payment_method;

```
for card in cards['data']: 
    card['fingerprint'] == removable_card: 
        stripe.Customer.delete_source(customer_id, card['id'])
```

that should be all